# Setting managed metadata field via Sharepoint Designer 2013 Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, managed-metadata

I'm trying to copy an item from one list to another via a workflow in Sharepoint 2013. I can create the item and set the fields to equal the Current Item's value for that corresponding field, and it works fine for most of the fields. However, it does not work for fields of type Managed Metadata. Anytime I try add that field and set its value and click OK in the Create List Item prompt it just disappears from the list of fields to be set.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: I've edited the title and question.

Answer (score 0):

So the real issue I was having was essentially just using a Workflow to copy a List item from one list to another. It appears that there is no good way to do this using a Sharepoint 2013 Workflow. However, I discovered that for a Sharepoint 2010 workflow this is a pretty trivial task because there is a predefined Action for this.